# Show action for a resource that is in a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource as follows:

```
resources :loads do
  resources :stops
end
```

Here is how I am calling my show action for stops

```
def show
  @load = Load.find(params[:load_id])
  @stop = @load.stops.find(params[:id])
end
```

However I am getting an error message as follows.

```
No route matches {:controller=>"stops", :action=>"show", :load_id=>#<Stop id: 62, load_id: 120, stop_type: "", stop_sequence: nil, stop_name: "", stop_address: "", stop_city: "", stop_state: "", stop_country: "", stop_postal: nil>}
```

What's causing this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: what's the url you're trying to access?

Comment: get '/loads/:load_id/stops/:id', controller: 'stops', action: 'show', as:'load_stop'

Comment: why do you redefine a `get`? this is given with your nested resource

Comment: Is that what is causing the issue?